# correlated normal random variables with arbitrary rho(corrcoef)

Tags: c++, math, statistics

i have question about generating correlated random variables...is there a way to generate x1(0, 1), x2(0, 1) which are normal to have rho = 0; or generate 
x3(0, 1), x4(0, 1) to have rho = 0.75 or something else?

i tried this so far

1- independent normal generator:

```
vector<double> uncorr_normal(double m, double s, int n)
{
random_device seed;
mt19937 gen{ seed() };

normal_distribution<> dist{ m, s };

vector<double> samples;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    samples.push_back(dist(gen));
}
return samples;
}
```

2- dependent normal generator:

```
pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> 
corr_normal(double m1, double s1, double m2, double s2, double rho, int n)
{
vector<double> X;
vector<double> Y;

random_device seed;
mt19937 gen{ seed() };

normal_distribution<> dist1{ m1, s1 };
normal_distribution<> dist2{ m2, s2 };

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    double x = dist1(gen);
    X.push_back(x);
    double y = rho * x + sqrt(1 - rho * rho) * dist2(gen);
    Y.push_back(y);
}
pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> pair(X, Y);
return pair;
```

}

i measure the correlation coefficient by the function i implemented below:

```
double rho(vector<double>& X, vector<double>& Y)
{
double sum_X = 0, sum_Y = 0, sum_XY = 0;
double squareSum_X = 0, squareSum_Y = 0;
//------------------------------------------
size_t n = max(X.size(), Y.size());
//------------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // sum of elements of array X.
    sum_X = sum_X + X[i];

    // sum of elements of array Y.
    sum_Y = sum_Y + Y[i];

    // sum of X[i] * Y[i].
    sum_XY = sum_XY + X[i] * Y[i];

    // sum of square of array elements.
    squareSum_X = squareSum_X + X[i] * X[i];
    squareSum_Y = squareSum_Y + Y[i] * Y[i];
}

// use formula for calculating correlation coefficient.
double corr = (double)(n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y)
    / (double)(sqrt((n * squareSum_X - sum_X * sum_X)
        * (n * squareSum_Y - sum_Y * sum_Y)));

//------------------------------------------
return corr;
```

}

however if i generate two uncorrelated random variables and test them with rho function i dont get rho = 0;

and for correlated case if i plugged in the random correlated vectors i dont get the specified rho either.

can you help me with this please?

best regards

Comment: I just run your code with 100.00 simulations and it looks fine. In the uncorrelated case it yields 0.00383497 and in the correlated case with `rho=0.5` it gives 0.503739. Maybe your sample size was not large enough?

Comment: I've tested it with 1000 iterations for "rho = 0.75",and it had a wide tolerance between  (0, 1)

Comment: I tried it with 1000 simulations and `rho=0.75`. I repeated this step 100 times and the outcome for rho is 0.752059 (average) 0.711403 (min) 0.789449 (max).

Comment: I really dont know what i'm doing wrong...ok thanks...i'll try different samples size and iterations , hope to get results...is there any more efficient way to perform this?any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I only tested the standard normal case. In other cases your correlated construction is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the correlated case you have to create standard normal samples, then transform and correlate them:

```
pair<vector<double>, vector<double>>
corr_normal(double m1, double s1, double m2, double s2, double rho, int n)
{
    vector<double> X;
    vector<double> Y;

    random_device seed;
    mt19937 gen{ seed() };

    normal_distribution<> dist1{ 0.0, 1.0 };
    normal_distribution<> dist2{ 0.0, 1.0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            double x = dist1(gen);
            X.push_back(m1 + x * s1);
            double y = m2 + s2*(rho * x + sqrt(1 - rho * rho) * dist2(gen));
            Y.push_back(y);
    }
    pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> pair(X, Y);
    return pair;
}
```

See http://www.statisticalengineering.com/bivariate_normal.htm

Comment: thank you dear max. if we have x1(5, 1) and x2(8, 1) with rho = 0.1, can we easily transform them to have say "rho = 0.9" with changing the parameters. i.e changing them to x1(5, 1.5) and x2(8.5, 2). can we do that?

Comment: i appreciate if there is any idea you can give me about the above question?

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. You have samples x~N(5,1), y~N(8,1) which are correlated by rho=0.1. Why you want to transform them into x1~N(5,1.5), y1~N(8.5,2) with rho=0.9? What is the problem with sampling again?

Comment: I just want to change the rho value along with scaling the normals, it will be better justification for my project